# What exactly is this grey colored popup called in MapKit & what method gets called when tapped?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

Ok I have this mapview with location pins, 5 shown here:

[image: Map Pin Locations]

But what is the grey popup that shows up when you tap a pin, called?

And what method gets called when you tap on the pin, that contains or fetches the pin data to be displayed on that grey call out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called callouts, and `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` is called when a pin is tapped. To see how to use them, I recommend this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

It's a private class and, as mentioned, is called an annotation callout. Check out https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview for an open source clone of it and http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/ for an open source clone of MapKit that uses it natively.